# Why won't my script copy the file I specify?

Tags: windows, batch

I'm making a batch script that replaces a file (`%ORIGINALFILE%`) in a given path (`%PROGPATH%`) with a new file (`%PATCH%`). The path is in a folder that requires UAC, so the script needs to be run as admin, but this doesn't seem to work. Whenever I run my script, a message prints that reads *"0 file(s) were copied."*. I was able to copy the file before I added error messages, why after adding my messages does my script no longer copy my patch file? Here is the final version of my script:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Patch
MODE con cols=56 lines=5

IF EXIST "%PROGPATH%\%ORIGINALFILE%.bak" GOTO :ERROR

:RENAME
CD "%PROGPATH%\"
RENAME "%ORIGINALFILE%" "%ORIGINALFILE%.bak"

XCOPY "%PATCH%" "%PROGPATH%\%ORIGINALFILE%"
ECHO.
ECHO The patch was successful.
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :END

:ERROR
ECHO.
ECHO You've already installed the patch.
ECHO.
PAUSE
:END
```

Comment: Your logic seems wrong: you are checking for the back-up file only when the original doesn't exist, which is never the case after running this script, unless the patch file is missing. Also `GOTO :PATCH` and `GOTO :SUCCESS` are completely unnecessary, since the targets are the immediately following lines.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where %PROGPATH% and %ORIGINALFILE% are defined. If these are system variables, do note that running as admin runs as a DIFFERENT user, and so its likely those are empty.

Comment: I have tried all suggestions with no luck. I have also updated my script code to my current version.